# sqlite3 schema for flask poll app

Tags: sqlite, database-schema, flask

I'm a [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/) beginner and I want to build a poll app using flask and sqlite3 as the database engine.

My question is how can I create two tables, 'questions' and 'choices' so that each question has some choices(may not be a fixed number.

My orginal approach was rather naive:

```
drop table if exists entries;
create table question (
    ques_id integer primary key autoincrement,
    ques string not null,
    choice1 string not null,
    choice2 string not null,
    choice3 string not null,
    choice4 string not null,
    pub_date integer
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a more [normalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) approach. This is good for storing a separate set of choices common to all questions.

```
CREATE TABLE choices (
    choice_id integer primary key autoincrement,
    choice string not null
);

CREATE TABLE questions (
    ques_id integer primary key autoincrement,
    ques string not null,
    choice_id integer,
    FOREIGN KEY(choice_id) REFERENCES choice(choice_id)
);
```

Example interpreter session:

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
>>> c = conn.cursor()
>>> c.execute("""CREATE TABLE choices (
...     choice_id integer primary key autoincrement,
...     choice string not null
... );""")
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x7f29f60b8ce8>
>>> c.execute("""CREATE TABLE questions (
...     ques_id integer primary key autoincrement,
...     ques string not null,
...     choice_id integer,
...     pub_date integer,
...     FOREIGN KEY(choice_id) REFERENCES choice(choice_id)
... );""")
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x7f29f60b8ce8>
>>> c.execute("INSERT INTO choices (choice) VALUES ('yes')")
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x7f29f60b8ce8>
>>> c.execute("""INSERT INTO questions (ques,choice_id) 
                 VALUES ('do you like sqlite?',1)""")
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x7f29f60b8ce8>
>>> c.execute("""SELECT ques, choice 
                   FROM questions q 
                        JOIN choices c ON c.choice_id = q.choice_id;""")
>>> c.fetchall()
[(u'do you like sqlite?', u'yes')]
```

Comment: @Adam- just to clear up my confusion... what's happening in the last line of the schema?

Comment: @infoquad: I can't do better than SQLite's own excellent documentation on the subject: http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html Cheers.